# Forms and inputs Udacity

Tags: python

I have been working on the same problem for a month and I still don't know how I can fix my code. I am on udacity web development lesson 2. I been posting on stackoverflow and Udacity discussion for a little awhile, but I don't know how to fix it. I know someone has done the lesson and finish the code. Can someone post the code so I can see how it was done. My code is post at the bottom.
import webapp2

```
form="""  
<form method="post">
    What is your birthday?
    <br>
    <label>Month<input type="type" name="month"></label>
    <label>Day<input type="type" name="day"></label>
    <label>Year<input type="type" name="year"></label>
    <div style="color: red">%(error)s</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form> 
"""
def valid_year(year):
        if year and year.isdigit():
            year = int(year)
            if year > 1900 and year < 2020:
                return year

def valid_day(day):
        if day and day.isdigit():
            day = int(day)
            if day > 0 and day <= 31:
                return day

 months = ['Janurary',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']

    month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(),m) for m in months)

def valid_month(month):
        if month:
            short_month =  month[:3].lower()
            return month_abbvs.get(short_month)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()
        self.valid_year(year)
        self.valid_day(day)
        self.valid_month(month)


    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))
        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.write_form("That doesn't look valid to me, friend.")
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is?

Comment: You have to enter your name. If you miss spell you name, put a unknown year, or put a day that beyond 31 then it says  "That doesn't look valid to me, friend.". If its correct it says "Thanks! That's a totally valid day!".

Answer (score 0):

`This my code and it finally works. try it and it will work

import webapp2

form='''
   
    What is your birthday?

```
<label>Month
    <input type="text" name="Month">
</label>

<label>Day
    <input type="text" name="Day">
</label>

<label>Year
    <input type="text" name="Year">
</label>

<br/>
<br/>

<input type='submit'>
```

'''

months = ['January',
             'February',
             'March',
             'April',
             'May',
             'June',
             'July',
             'August',
             'September',
             'October',
             'November',
             'December']

```
month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months)

  def valid_month(month):
   if month:
       short_month = month[:3].lower()
       return month_abbvs.get(short_month)

  def valid_day(day):
   if day.isdigit():
      return int(day) if int(day) in range(1,32) else None
   else:
       return None
  def valid_year(year):
   if year.isdigit():
       return int(year) if int(year) in range(1900, 2021) else None
   else:
       return None

  class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
       self.response.out.write(form)

   def post(self):
       #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
       user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('Month'))
       user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('Day'))
       user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('Year'))
       if not(user_day and user_year and user_month):
           self.response.out.write(form)
       else:
           self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")
```

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
       ('/', MainPage),
   ], debug=True)

Comment: actually i don't know why it doesn't write in the same way i wrote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm so glad to meet an Udacity student :)

I'm in "backend" course now.

So, There're several problems in your code.

**1. IndentationError: unexpected indent**

> months = ['Janurary',
>
> ```
> one space before "months"
> ```
>
> month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(),m) for m in months)
>
> ```
> four spaces before "month_abbvs"
> ```

**2. AttributeError: 'MainPage' object has no attribute 'valid_year'**

> self.valid_year(year)
>
> self.valid_day(day)
>
> self.valid_month(month)
>
> ```
> valid_* methods are not in the "MainPage" class so delete the "self" keyword.
> ```

**3. NameError: global name 'year' is not defined**

> Actually "get" method in "MainPage" class only for show input and
> messages.
>
> Your "form"s method is "post". So, your parameters only need in
> "post" method.
>
> Remove your "get" methods calling valid_* codes. then, It works fine.